# The origin of "salve" as a greeting (A origem de "salve" como uma saudação)

Tags: etimologia, cumprimentos

"Salve" is sometimes heard from some people as a greeting.
If I don't misunderstood, "salve" is also used as an honorific salutation, often including the designated person's name, as in "Salve Fulano!" (without a comma), to state a merit or dignity of honor.

Why "salve" is used as a greeting, and why this can have a honorable connotation?

---

"Salve" é ás vezes ouvido ser dito por algumas pessoas como uma saudação.
Se não estou enganado, "salve" também é usado como uma saudação honorífica, geralmente incluindo o nome da pessoa alvo, como em "Salve Fulano!" (sem vírgula), para declarar um merecimento ou dignidade de honra.

Por que "salve" é usado como uma saudação, e ainda por que pode ter uma conotação honrosa?

Comment: Reminds me of [***Salve**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salve#Latin) Regina, mater misericoridae*, a Latin hymn to Mary. The Portuguese and Spanish would appear to derive directly from the Latin.

Comment: Good question.  I suddenly realize that I hardly hear anyone use "salve" in Brazil nowadays.  It is still used In religious contexts, in some old songs ("Salve a loirinha!", "Salve o Corinthians", in our "National Anthem") but I would be surprised if I heard it from a youth.

Comment: @Centaurus  Yeah, this appears more often on historical or honorific contexts. Nowadays  is practically unused, except if the person is intentionally saying this way.

Comment: @Centaurus "Salve" is very commonly used amongst young men who listen to Brazilian Rap, specially in the form "mandar um salve". It is the name of [a music by Racionais MCs](http://letras.mus.br/racionais-mcs/721397/) and it can be found in some [informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/mandar%20um%20salve/) or [slang](http://dicionario.babylon.com/mandar_um_salve/) dictionaries.

Comment: @gmauch   It may be used within a certain group, but generally speaking very few people use it in ordinary conversation.  In the region where I live "Brazilian Rap" is somewhat restricted to the "favelas" and take my word for it, I very rarely hear it,  An n-gram might help if one could be found in Portuguese.

Comment: @Centaurus I agree it is restricted to a group, but I wanted to say it's use is not rare in informal conversations and would not surprise me to hear that from a youth.

Answer (score 2):

No latim, [salve](http://pt.glosbe.com/pt/la/ol%C3%A1) era a forma de saudar a uma pessoa (a várias pessoas dizia-se *salvete*).  Obviamente nos contextos formais ainda há rasgos dessa língua, e *salve* parece ser uma das expressões que ficou.

Comment: @gmauch https://pt.glosbe.com/pt/la/olá

Comment: E quanto ao uso honorífico dessa saudação?